# Is it possible to transform fnmatch.translate("**/*.py") into a semantically correct regex?

Tags: python, regex

Is there any easy way (or possible) to transform the output of `fnmatch.translate` into a regex that matches zero or more directories?

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> fnmatch.translate("**/*.py")
'.*.*\\/.*\\.py\\Z(?ms)'
```

What I want is the regex fragment to put at `___` in

```
dirs = ['a.py', 'b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']
r = fnmatch.translate("**/*.py").replace(".*.*", "___")
```

so that

```
[d for d in dirs if re.match(r, d)] == dirs
```

This attempt doesn't match in the the first two:

```
fnmatch.translate("**/*.py").replace('.*.*', "(.*/.*)*")
```

this doesn't match the first:

```
fnmatch.translate("**/*.py").replace('.*.*', "(.*/?)*")
```

and this makes the interpreter hang:

```
fnmatch.translate("**/*.py").replace('.*.*', "(.*|(.*/.*))*")
```

I'll be happy with an answer explaining why it isn't possible too..

**Update:** just replacing `**/` with the empty string doesn't work:

```
dirs = ['a.py', 'b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']

def translate(pat, repl=None):
    r = fnmatch.translate(pat)
    if repl:
        r = r.replace(".*.*", repl)
    r = re.compile(r)
    return [d for d in dirs if r.match(d)]

>>> print translate("**/*.py".replace("**/", ""))
['a.py', 'b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']  # correct
>>> print translate("b/**/*.py".replace("**/", ""))
['b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']  # correct
>>> print translate("b/**/b.py".replace("**/", ""))
['b/a.py']  # incorrect
```

Comment: why not `fnmatch.translate("*.py")`?

Comment: because that wouldn't allow e.g. `"b/**/*.py"`, ie. all .py files under `b` (the last three items in `dirs`).

Comment: `b/*.py` will have the same effect, since the `*` there is implicitly `**`.

Comment: it does allow all `.py` files under `foo`. Try `pattern = pattern.replace("**/", "")`.

Comment: That won't work with `"b/**/a.py"`..

Comment: BTW, `**` isn't part of fnmatch as standardized by POSIX, which is part of why its failure to be handled here isn't strictly a bug. (Recursing, on the other hand, _is_ a bug).

Comment: then `pattern.replace("**/*", "*")` and `pattern.replace("**/", "*")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually -- you don't need to change `.*.*` at all, except to a single `.*`; rather, you need to change a *single, unpaired* `.*` to be `[^/]*`.

Thus, the actual translation table needed is -- not using `fnmatch.translate()` at all, but rolling it yourself:

```
`?` -> `.`
`.` -> `[.]`
`**/` -> `(?:.*/)?`
`*` -> `[^/]*`
```

Correctly handling `[!foo]` and its ilk is best done copying the logic from the upstream `translate` code.

---

Applying these rules transforms `**/*.py` to `(?:.*/)?[^/]*[.]py`, which matches all four of the names in your question:

```
>>> import re
>>> dirs = ['a.py', 'b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']
>>> py_re = re.compile('(?:.*/)?[^/]*[.]py')
>>> [ 'Matches' if py_re.match(x) else 'Non-Matching' for x in dirs ]
['Matches', 'Matches', 'Matches', 'Matches']
```

---

An implementation of the transform:

```
def build_re(glob_str):
    opts = re.compile('([.]|[*][*]/|[*]|[?])|(.)')
    out = ''
    for (pattern_match, literal_text) in opts.findall(glob_str):
        if pattern_match == '.':
            out += '[.]'
        elif pattern_match == '**/':
            out += '(?:.*/)?'
        elif pattern_match == '*':
            out += '[^/]*'
        elif pattern_match == '?':
            out += '.'
        elif literal_text:
            out += literal_text
    return out
```

Comment: Eh..?  `"**/*.py"` -> `".[^/]*[^/]*.py"`  (that only finds the second item)

Comment: @thebjorn, no, `**/*.py` -> `.*/[^/]*[.]py`. (I left out the `.` -> `[.]` substitution, which could also be written `.` -> `\.` but with more potential for quoting bugs).

Comment: @thebjorn, note that you can't apply those things in order, one after another, since they match each other; you need to do a single pass and replace them whenever they're found in the original.

Comment: Also, not all implementations make `**/` completely optional (not requiring a `/`). The test data you gave above indicates that you want this, so I've modified my answer to adopt that behavior, but be aware that it's not going to match all other globbing engines' behavior.

Comment: Thus, with that change, one gets `(?:.*/)?[^/]*[.]py`, which matches all four of the paths in your question.

Comment: Now I don't feel so bad for not coming up with this myself ;-)  I've updated the question with an implementation of your algorithm.

Comment: FWIW, it'd actually be a bit more typical to put such an interpretation in your own answer -- that way it can be independently upvoted/downvoted/commented on/etc., separately from the question itself.

Comment: Yours is a bit more complete, if it preserves upstream translate's handling for bracket expressions. Should that be the case, I'd say it's worth having as its own answer as well.

Comment: (Hmm. I wonder if I misread what you first added as an addendum to your question -- at the time, I thought I saw the handling for `[!...]` found in upstream translate() there).

Comment: I didn't really know about `[!...]`, but I've added handling of it that matches the semantics of node.js' minimax library (Python's `pathlib` doesn't seem to handle it).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non-regex implementation of Charles' translation algorithm.

*update1:* this version handles leading `!` as negation of the entire pattern, similarly to node.js' minimatch (https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#comparisons-to-other-fnmatchglob-implementations).

```
def charles(pat):
    r = ""
    negate = int(pat.startswith('!'))
    i = negate

    while i < len(pat):
        if pat[i:].startswith('**/'):
            r += "(?:.*/)?"
            i += 3
        elif pat[i] == "*":
            r += "[^/]*"
            i += 1
        elif pat[i] == ".":
            r += "[.]"
            i += 1
        elif pat[i] == "?":
            r += "."
            i += 1
        else:
            r += pat[i]
            i += 1

    def match(d):
        m = re.match(r, d)
        return not m if negate else m

    return [d for d in dirs if match(d)]

print charles("**/*.py")
print charles("b/**/*.py")
print charles("b/**/a.py")
print charles("!b/**/a.py")
```

which prints

```
# (?:.*/)?[^/]*[.]py
['a.py', 'b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']
# b/(?:.*/)?[^/]*[.]py
['b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']
# b/(?:.*/)?a[.]py
['b/a.py', 'b/c/a.py', 'b/c/d/a.py']
# b/(?:.*/)?a[.]py
['a.py']
```

*update2:* handling negations the way `fnmatch` does is a little more convoluted (basically `fnmatch` treats `[!...]` similarly to the regex `[^...]`):

```
def translate(pat):
    r = ""
    i = 0
    L = len(pat)

    while i < L:
        if pat[i:].startswith('**/'):
            r += "(?:.*/)?"
            i += 3
        elif pat[i] == "*":
            r += "[^/]*"
            i += 1
        elif pat[i] == ".":
            r += "[.]"
            i += 1
        elif pat[i] == "?":
            r += "."
            i += 1
        elif pat[i] == '[':
            i += 1
            j = i
            if j < L and pat[j] == '!':
                j += 1
            if j < L and pat[j] == ']':  # make sure [!] => \[\!\]
                j += 1
            while j < L and pat[j] != ']':
                j += 1
            if j >= L:
                r += '\\['  # didn't find a closing ']', backtracking
            else:
                stuff = pat[i:j].replace('\\', '\\\\')
                i = j+1
                if stuff[0] == '!':
                    stuff = '^' + stuff[1:]  # translate negation
                elif stuff[0] == '^':
                    stuff = '\\' + stuff     # quote ^ character
                r = '%s[%s]' % (r, stuff)
        else:
            r += re.escape(pat[i])
            #r += pat[i]
            i += 1
    r += '\\Z(?ms)'
    return r
```

(the negation code is stolen almost verbatim from fnmatch..)

Comment: I'm not sure this actually does cover the negation case -- it appears to be looking for a `!` at the start of the entire pattern, rather than at the start of a bracket expression, and applying the negation likewise. Might be worth looking at the Python standard-library code for the original translate implementation.

Comment: Looks good to me. Alas, I have but one upvote to give (and it's already there).